# Parent Element getting Undefined while copying elements using jQuery Clone in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone, jquery-clone

I am using [jQuery Clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy elements

Cloned html:

```
<TABLE id="vehicleSelectTbl" name="vehicleSelectTbl"> 
    <TBODY> 
        <TABLE id="vehicleCustomTbl" name="vehicleCustomTbl"> 
            <TBODY> 
                <TR>
                    <TD width="240"> 
                        <STRONG style="FONT-WEIGHT: normal">Equipment $</STRONG> 
                        <INPUT onkeyup="SetDataChangedFlag()" onblur="" id="Veh_2_Equipment" value="0" name="Veh_1_Equipment" onChange=""> 
                    </TD> 
               </TR> 
            </TBODY> 
        </TABLE> 
     </TBODY> 
</TABLE>
```

Input Field

```
<input onkeyup="SetDataChangedFlag()" onblur="ValidateEquipment(this)" id="Veh_1_Equipment" value="0" name="Veh_1_Equipment">
```

Here is my JS code

```
    var $jVehClone1 =  jQuery("#vehicleSelectTbl").clone(true);

    $jVehClone1.find('#Veh_1_Equipment').attr("onblur", "");
    $jVehClone1.find('#Veh_1_Equipment').blur(function () {ValidateEquipment(this)});
    $jVehClone1.find('#Veh_1_Equipment').attr("onChange", "");
    $jVehClone1.find('#Veh_1_Equipment').change(function () {SetDataChangedFlag()});
    $jVehClone1.find('#Veh_1_Equipment').attr('id', 'Veh_'+newNum+'_Equipment').attr('name', 'Veh_'+newNum+'_Equipment');

    $jVehClone1.appendTo('#myVehicleTable');
```

Issue:
I am able to copy elements using Clone method and works ok, but when I am searching for

```
document.forms[0].elements["Veh_1_Equipment"].value
```

It returns **Undefined**

`document.forms[0].elements["Veh_2`_Equipment"].value

It returns expected o/p

Above Issue only happens in IE (My Installed IE version is 11)

**Do any one having any Idea why my parent element "Veh_1_Equipment" value is getting undefined ?**

Comment: Can you post the original element tree. The one that gets copied. Have you tried to log the `$jVehClone1` to the console. That way you can inspect which elements are in there.

Comment: <TABLE id="vehicleSelectTbl" name="vehicleSelectTbl">
<TBODY>
 <TABLE id="vehicleCustomTbl" name="vehicleCustomTbl">
  <TBODY>
   <TR>
    <TD width="240">
     <STRONG style="FONT-WEIGHT: normal">Equipment $</STRONG>
     <INPUT onkeyup="SetDataChangedFlag()" onblur="" id="Veh_2_Equipment" value="0" name="Veh_1_Equipment" onChange="">
    </TD>
   </TR>
  </TBODY>
 </TABLE>    
</TBODY>
</TABLE>

Comment: Thank you. I still can't see a form element to which you are referring?

Comment: I think I get it. `document.forms[0].elements["Veh_1_Equipment"].value` is the original element, but that isn't part of a form. While `document.forms[0].elements["Veh_2_Equipment"].value` gets a new id from your code and is appended to a form? Am I correct?

Comment: @Mouser - Elements which I am copying is inside form
<form name="VehicleForm" id="VehicleForm" action="VehF_Data.cfm" method="POST">
and div where I am appending also inside form
<div id="myVehicleTable" name="myVehicleTable"></div>

FYI: In FF it works well

Comment: Then post your complete relevant coding or a relevant fiddle. We can't help you debug if we don't have all the code that is involved.